# Setting custom font to Dialog

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, android-appcompat

We are trying to set the title of a dialog to have a custom font so we tried doing a theme with the following:

```xml
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Dialog.Title</item>
</style>


<style name="Dialog.Title" parent="RtlOverlay.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat">
  <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Dialog.TextAppearance.Title</item>
</style>


<style name="Dialog.TextAppearance.Title" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
  <item name="fontFamily">@font/custom_font</item>
</style>
```

And we are creating the dialog builder like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DialogTheme), R.style.DialogTheme)
```

The style and text appearance are completely ignored. For other styles, it seems to be working.

We managed to make it work by copying the layout used by `AppCompat` and adding it as a custom title:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- modified from AppCompat's abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml -->
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|start|left"
  android:paddingLeft="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
  android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
    style="@style/Dialog.Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    tools:text="Some title" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Based on this: [abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml)

Instead of using `DialogTitle` here we are using `TextView`. What `DialogTitle` is overloading onMeasure with the following:

```java
final Layout layout = getLayout();
if (layout != null) {
    final int lineCount = layout.getLineCount();
    if (lineCount > 0) {
        final int ellipsisCount = layout.getEllipsisCount(lineCount - 1);
        if (ellipsisCount > 0) {
            setSingleLine(false);
            setMaxLines(2);
            final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(null,
                    R.styleable.TextAppearance,
                    android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium,
                    android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
            final int textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_textSize, 0);
            if (textSize != 0) {
                // textSize is already expressed in pixels
                setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            }
            a.recycle();
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

We think it's related with it setting the text size, but we are not sure. We have a working hack (with the copied layout). However, we would prefer to know how we can make it work with xml styles and themes instead of having to change the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer to another question I just posted recently, this is how I was able to programmatically set the font of all attributes of an `AlertDialog`. Hope it works for you.

```
Typeface semibold = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.product_bold);
Typeface regular = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.product_regular);
AlertDialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Your title")
        .setMessage("Your message.")
        .setPositiveButton("Your button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //your code
            }
        }).show();
int titleText = getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
((TextView) myDialog.getWindow().findViewById(titleText)).setTypeface(semibold);
TextView dialogMessage = myDialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
Button dialogButton = myDialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
dialogMessage.setTypeface(regular);
dialogButton.setTypeface(semibold);
```

Confirmed working on Android 9.0, can't claim for it to work on older APIs.

Another method of programmatically setting the title with a TextView, this is how I used to do it:

```
TextView alertTitle = findViewById(R.id.alertTextTemp);
if (alertTitle.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewGroup) alertTitle.getParent()).removeView(alertTitle);
}
alertTitle.setText("Warning");
alertTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
alertTitle.setTypeface(semibold);
```

Then when you create your dialog, you set a custom title with:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setCustomTitle(alertTitle)...
```

alertTitle being a TextView in your `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alertTextTemp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:paddingLeft="23dp"
    android:paddingTop="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Those attributes on the TextView I had to fine tune to get it as close to the default title margins and size as possible, you might want to verify it works for you.

Comment: In the end we resorted to setting a custom title view instead. As we wanted to infer the font from the theme and not have to do it programmatically.